# weird error of loading mysql data to javascript variable using php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I have accessed a database and fetched data (to make it simple, let's assume only one data), the data is an array and has one field 'link', which is a url.

I pass the value of $data['link'] to a php variable $l1; to compare, I also pass the actual url to another varibale $l2.

Then the next two lines try to pass the value to javascript variable. If I remove the first line (echo "var link1 = \"$l1\";";), it works; if I keep the first line, it doesn't (alert dialog not shown). I think it is the problem of the url, but the value of $l2 is exactly the same as $data['link'], the next two lines also appear the same in the source code of the html page.

Code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readData() {
alert('haha1');
<?php
$l1 = $data['link'];
$l2 = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Affenpinscher.jpg";
echo "var link1 = \"$l1\";";
echo "var link2 = \"$l2\";";
?>
alert('haha2');
}
</script>
<body onload="readData();"></body>
```

Anyone have any idea why this happen? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Can you post the html source code that is generated as a result? Sounds to me like this might be a Javascript problem and not a PHP thing...

Comment: Also, try changing the declaration of $l1 to: `$l1 = "http://... (the same as $l2)` and see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I've understood your doubt. At any case, from intuition, I'd try out something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function readData() {
alert('haha1');
<?php
$l1 = json_encode($data['link']);
$l2 = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/Affenpinscher.jpg";
echo "var link1 = ".$l1.";";
echo "var link2 = \"$l2\";";
?>
alert('haha2');
}
</script>
<body onload="readData();"></body>
```

Your URL might be "malformed" for javascript; and cause a parse error.
Let us know if this was the case...

Comment: it works! A further question: when should I use "json_encode"?

Comment: You can use it to convert arrays into JSON, for serialization purposes (IE you need to "transfer" your data accross a non PHP layer); but it's also a handy function in cases as yours, when you basically need escaping.